# Можно ли задать порядок инициализации свойств UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, usercontrol

Есть наследник от UserControl. Он имеет ряд свойств, которые зависят друг от друга (какие то привязками, какие то явно). Все работает, при отображении я вижу то, что ожидаю. Но во время отладки я обращаю внимание на то, что некоторые свойства вызываются по много раз. Можно ли задать порядок их инициализации? Свой контрол я пока не буду приводить в пример, там очень много всего, но приведу TextBlock.

Допустим я делаю TextBlock. Чтобы вывести текст, я должен получить значение свойства Text, стили шрифта, вычислить на их основании ширину надписи и задать контролу ширину, соответствующую ширине строки (на самом деле в этом контроле происходит все иначе, но предположим, что именно так). Так вот ширина строки привязана к стилям шрифта и тексту. и каждый раз, когда меняется текст или стиль, ширина пересчитывается. Это удобно во время работы, но не во время инициализации. Зачем мне пересчитывать ширину строки до чтения свойства Text?

Не очень удачный пример, наверное, но смысл, думаю, понятен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо пересчитывать всё полностью при каждом изменении любого свойства. Отложите расчёты до момента, когда все свойства контрола заданы. Например, делайте первый пересчёт по событию `Loaded`.

Ещё XAML поддерживает атрибут `DependsOnAttribute`, который позволяет описывать зависимости между свойствами. Но это костыль, который в самом WPF используется только в исключительных случаях, в частности, для триггеров и сеттеров.

Comment: А как я их отложу, а потом включу?

Comment: @iRumba Вы ничего не "выключаете". Все значения присваиваются свойствам в произвольном порядке, а долгие расчёты вы проводите после полной загрузки, когда все свойства уже заданы.

Comment: А как я узнаю, что все свойства заданы? Вот есть мультиконвертер, в него передается 7 свойств. Конвертер вызывается сразу, как значение присваивается первому свойству, а потом каждый раз, когда присваивается остальным. Я не знаю, как проверить, присвоились ли значения остальным.

Comment: @iRumba Если конвертер настолько тяжёлый и сложный, то это не конвертер. Вынесите логику в VM да всё. А в VM обрабатывайте `Loaded`.

Comment: Я не сказал, что он тяжелый и сложный. Он выполняет обычные математические операции и преобразования и выдает фигуру, которая строится по точкам и имеет нужную трансформацию. Просто это всего один элемент управления. В бою их будет много. И каждый будет вызывать конвертер 7 раз вместо одного. Это не повредит работе, это утяжелит инициализацию окна. А точнее открытие файла со схемой. Я понимаю, что всем крупным компаниям пофиг, сколько будет инициализироваться их ПО и открываться документ, 5 секунд или минуту. Но я не крупная компания :)

Comment: @iRumba: Ну так навесьте мультиконвертер на `Loaded`, а не в XAML'е.

Comment: Хочу добавить, что `Loaded` не так прост как кажется. К примеру, если вы свернете и развернете окно приложения `Loaded` сработает повторно. Так что, если планируете использовать событие `Loaded` для инициализации, советую отписаться от этого события в конце его обработчика.

Comment: @Gromy Вы с каким-нибудь `Activated` не путаете? `Loaded` и `Initialized` не должны срабатывать при сворачивании и разворачивании. Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx), `Loaded` может сработать повторно при смене темы, например.

Comment: @Discord, да, вы правы, проверил - все хорошо работает. Возможно у меня с другим событием проблемы ранее были, с ходу не смог воспроизвести проблемную ситуацию.

Comment: @VladD, не люблю выносить часть хамла в код.... потом самому разобраться сложно. (